# Detect triple click with InputBindings WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to detect triple click on an Image element in my ViewModel.

So I have this in my View

```
  <Image MouseDown="Image_MouseDown"  Margin="0 0 20 0" Source="..." HorizontalAlignment="Right"  >
     <Image.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}"/>
     </Image.InputBindings>
  </Image>
```

And this code in my ViewModel:

```
     public ICommand MouseDoubleClickCommand { get; } = new RelayCommandParametrized(obj =>
     {

           // Detect here triple click
    });
```

The problem is that ClickCount exists in a MouseButtonEventArgs and can't find my way to that value in the viewmodel.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can't you use custom `behavior`? or use `PreviewMouseDown` with `interaction`, there you can get count of clicks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why three clicks? It's not a common requirement

Comment: @Alexey what do you mean by custom behavior?

Comment: @FrancescoB. right, it is not common, that is why i need it, i want to have a hidden area on the app that will respond to triple click and will trigger certain functionality.

Comment: That sounds almost as intuitive as a double-rightclick. Any chance you can spare your users from doing that altogether? Maybe someone at [UX-Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) can help you find an alternative. If it's intentionally hidden, a triple click can happen accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

So, I love ReactiveExtensions and I will use them. Take a look at [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/).

First of all, you will need reactiveui-events nuget package.

Then, create extension method:

```
 public static IObservable<Unit> TripleClick(this ButtonBase element, int totalMillisecondsLimit = 1000)
    {
        return element.Events().Click // get clicks
             .Select(x => Unit.Default).TimeInterval().Select(x => x.Interval) // get time intervals between them
             .Window(3) // always look at last 3
             .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray()) // just make array from observable produced by Window
             .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Sum(z => z.TotalMilliseconds) < totalMillisecondsLimit) // check if the 3 clicks are very close to each other
             .Select(x => Unit.Default); // you can return whatever you want, Unit.Default is Reactive version of void
    }
```

Then in xaml.cs of your view you can use something like this:

```
 Button.TripleClick().Subscribe(click =>
            {

            });

            // or

  Button.TripleClick().InvokeCommand(ViewModel.SomeCommand);
```

Beware, that in WPF you should dispose those subscriptions. Preferably, by using [WhenActivated](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/)

And to be honest, I believe that you can wrap this in WPF Interaction or Behaviour and then be able to bind to TripleClick in XAML.

Answer (score -2):

You need to implement interaction trigger.

Add Reference in XAML

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"

<Image MouseDown="Image_MouseDown"  Margin="0 0 20 0" Source="..." HorizontalAlignment="Right"  >

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LeftDoubleClick" >
         <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}"
             PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```